# Banshee crashing, unable to list a DVD in its browser panel on Xubuntu

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, banshee, dvd

I just upgraded to Raring Ringtail and I decided to start using Banshee, it looks great and integrated DVDs and videos is a major plus point.

I can't get Banshee to list the DVD in its browser unless it's mounted, and when I click the entry to play the mounted DVD it just crashes.

I put a bounty on the question now because I came to Banshee from clementine because that had different problems. I'm not getting this sorted out on my own too quick and people are demanding to play their DVDs.

I figured it should be like a music CD and just be playable without being mounted. It looks like I need to mount the DVD to see it in the browser panel, but that requires extra interaction with xubuntu outside Banshee. If anyone can answer that I'd be grateful, but the bounty is for a solution to the crashing.

I've got libdvdcss2 installed and gstreamer-ugly.

I have the option in the Extensions preferences checked to play DVDs and CDs.

This is the error I get when running it from the CLI and trying to play a DVD:

```
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
*** Zero check failed in ifo_read.c:570
    for vmgi_mat->zero_3 = 0x00000000010000000000000000000000000000
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.0
libdvdread: Using libdvdcss version 1.2.12 for DVD access
*** Zero check failed in ifo_read.c:570
    for vmgi_mat->zero_3 = 0x00000000010000000000000000000000000000
libdvdnav: DVD Title: Sandmann
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 3b1f5a2b
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): 
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/adam/.dvdnav/Sandmann.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x0000011d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x00005d30
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x00005f9a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 1 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'de' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: de 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'de' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: de 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'de' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: de 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'de' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: de 

*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***

libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'de' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: de 

(Banshee:988): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_query: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(Banshee:988): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_query: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(Banshee:988): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_query: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***


** (Banshee:988): CRITICAL **: bp_get_subtitle_description: assertion `code != NULL' failed

*** libdvdread: CHECK_VALUE failed in nav_read.c:264 ***
*** for dsi->dsi_gi.zero1 == 0 ***

The program 'Banshee' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 44 error_code 11 request_code 149 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
adam@gondor:~$
```

Comment: First there is a memory crash happening to Banshee that is smashing it trying to keep a window drawn on-screen.  Secondly whatever library is in use is defaulting in odd ways.  It would be handy if you could please give us your system hardware specifications as that may be crucial to this problem.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8700  @ 2.53GHz

Comment: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

Comment: `adam@gondor:~$ free -h  
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:          3.7G       1.6G       2.2G         0B       179M       725M  
-/+ buffers/cache:       689M       3.1G  
Swap:         3.9G         0B       3.9G  `

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat what is the memory crash that you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a bit of help from the xubuntu irc channel.

It was basically the video drivers were no good.

What solved it was a combination or one of adding the gstreamer0.10-vaapi pkg, the i965-va-driver pkg, adding that ubuntu-x-swat ppa and rebooting.

This has got rid of the crashing in banshee and parole.